# Is Speech Runtime Executable spying on me in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu, privacy, microphone, cortana

When looking at task manager I see Speech Runtime Executable always taking a bit of CPU

[image: Microsoft Is Spying]

Cortana (not Hey Cortana) is **ON** and Hey Cortana is **OFF** is enabled and these are my privacy settings

[image: PRIV8]

My computer has a built in microphone and I do not like Microsoft spying so I also have disabled some diagnostic and telemetry services

Are they listening to me?

Comment: Microsoft isn't spying on you.  If you want want Cortana to respond to your voice commands and/or Cortana.

Comment: Hey cortana is off

Comment: Your question says "Cortana is enabled". Your comment says "cortana is off". One of these statements is false (it cannot be enabled and off at the same time). Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, Cortana is on but hey cortana is off

Comment: @Ramhound They do. By default when Cortana is ON "Hey Cortana" (which is a Cortana feature) is OFF. You have to enable Hey Cortana (which I did not to protect my privacy)

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Cortana is not only a text-to-speech converter. Its a virtual assistant which needs to be able to activated by voice commands (explains how it can detect it whenever you say "Hey Cortana") and to achieve that it needs to be "listening". That being said Cortana doesn't send whatever it hears to Microsoft. It's not a whistleblower :P . Information it stores comes from your interactions with it.

Comment: Cortana is not open and provides is still taking CPU. Also Hey Cortana is off

Comment: A whistleblower let it known that recordings are actually used by external parties and not just used locally. Source: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/08/microsoft-will-continue-human-voice-recording-review-and-its-privacy-policy-says-so/